# Why is this boolean variable assigned true?

Tags: java, assignment-operator, operator-precedence, boolean-expression

I have the following two code snippets which produce different outputs:

```
boolean a = false, b = false, c = false, d = false;
if (a = false | (b = false) || (c = true) | (d = true)){

}
System.out.println("if (a = false | (b = false) || (c = true) | (d = true))");
System.out.printf("a=%b\nb=%b\nc=%b\nd=%b\n\n", a, b, c, d);


if ((a = false) | (b = false) || (c = true) | (d = true)){

}
System.out.println("if ((a = false) | (b = false) || (c = true) | (d = true))");
System.out.printf("a=%b\nb=%b\nc=%b\nd=%b\n", a, b, c, d);
```

When running the above code I get the following output:

```
if (a = false | (b = false) || (c = true) | (d = true))
a=true
b=false
c=true
d=true

if ((a = false) | (b = false) || (c = true) | (d = true))
a=false
b=false
c=true
d=true
```

Please note that `a` is assigned `true` in the first snippet, but not in the second.

Why would wrapping the assigment of `a` in parentheses make such a difference?

Please note that I'm using assignment operators (`=`) and **not comparison operators (`==`) intentionally**.

Comment: @Eran I am not wanting to compare, I am setting it to false. but why is it becoming true?

Comment: @JohnE.: then why on earth are you using an if statement?

Comment: @Stultuske There is nothing wrong with assignment in an if statement.

Comment: @luk2302 I am not confusing it, I am assigning it.

Comment: @JohnE.: there's nothing wrong with using your underwear as a hat. Do you do that as well? Why would you use an if statement if you're not going to have a condition?

Comment: @luk2302 well I didn't realise people would see it that way, but I edited title thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), the `|` operator has a higher precedence than the assignment operator `=`. Therefore, when you don't wrap `(a = false)` in parentheses :

```
if (a = false | (b = false) || (c = true) | (d = true))
```

is equivalent to

```
if (a = (false | (b = false) || (c = true) | (d = true)))
```

so you are assigning `true` to `a`.

On the other hand, in

```
if ((a = false) | (b = false) || (c = true) | (d = true))
```

you are assigning `false` to `a`.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that in the second case you are directly assigning `(a = false)` - therefore `a` will be false.

In the first case the value you actually assign to a is not `false` but

```
false | (b = false) || (c = true) | (d = true)
```

which is equivalent to

```
false | false || true | true
```

which is `true`.

Take a look at the [`operator precedence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) to see what is going here exactly:

- firstly the `|` is treated
- then the `||`
- then the `=`

Therefore the statement is calculated the following way:

```
a = false | (b = false) || (c = true) | (d = true)
a = false | false || true | true
a = true || false
a = true
```